# Redirect to download Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to track how many times file has been downloaded. I see it this way:

1) Instead of `<a href="{{ file.url }}" download>...</a>`, I should redirect user for `download` view; `<a href="download/{{ file.id }}/{{ file.name }}">...</a>`

> `file.id` and `file.name` needed for proper work of function bellow.

2) In my `download` view I need to registrate download of specific file, let's say I have `registrate_dl` function that does its job. Also, I need to take that `{{ file.url }}` value like in first link from first paragraph.

3) Finally, I registered download for specific file and got `{{ file.url }}` as `file_url` variable.

But, if, at the end of `view` function I place `return redirect(file_url)`, it just redirects me to file, without starting download.

---

So, how should i return this `file_url`, and trigger download?

Comment: You to trigger your view from frontend, click an anchor tag?

Comment: Why can't you just link to the download handler and then serve the file through the download view?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser How I can pass a file to return state? I thinking pass an url is only available way to return file somehow

Comment: What about apache logs for static files?

Comment: @PythonNewbie, you can possibly use text/xml as FB2 is an xml format. Your prior comment seems ot have been deleted under my question.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser yea, i deleted it cause found what your wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return the file as part of the response. How you go about it depends on the exact file type, but here is a CSV example I used from another answer.

```
def csv_view(request):
    filename =  "Your filename"
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.csv"',format(filename)
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow("Some stuff") 
    messages.success(request, 'Consultation added to report successfully!')
    messages.warning(request, 'Note: Certain needs may not appear in report, \
                                         this is a result of filtering process.')

    return response
```

Comment: @PythonNewbie, you can possibly use `text/xml` as FB2 is an xml format.